# SSAS on SQL Server Docker Linux Container With Java Application

Tags: java, sql-server, docker

I have start `SQL Server` Docker Container and i have `Java` as backend application which communicate with database.

I can do all the `JDBC` call without any issue.

Now i need to use `SSAS` to display data in `Pivot Table` in frontend. I am not sure if this is possible or not. Because most of tutorial says i need `IIS` server, which is windows specific application, the `SQL Server` is image on top of `Linux` OS image.

I got this [blog](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=103) which talks about connecting Java to SSAS (But it require  IIS). Since container OS is `Linux`, and `IIS` can't work with `Linux`.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-linux-2017) URL Microsoft says SSAS feature is part of SQL Server 2017 release.

Any Idea if this is possible or not?

Can i use `SASS` with `IIS`?

http://www.olap4j.org/ is for JAVA but it required `IIS`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server for Linux doesn't include SSAS, it's only available on the windows version.

Comment: is there any planning to port SSAS into linux containers?

Comment: another question: is it possible to setup SSAS in a Windows based image?